# add emoji to my android custom keyboard using 3rd party libraries

Tags: android-studio, keyboard, emoji

i'm trying to implement my own keyboard which support 2 language and also emoji , there is some repositories on git hub like *[this](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji)* and *[this](https://github.com/stefanhaustein/Emoji-1)* , which use almost same logic , the problem is that this libraries need a root view of my XML layout and an emoji edit text that declared in XML layout file , this is required to type in my own application but i want to implement a keyboard to type in other apps , so how i should handle that root view and emoji edit text ???

```
final EmojiPopup emojiPopup = EmojiPopup.Builder.fromRootView(rootView).build(emojiEditText);
```

Comment: have you found any solution in it?